# ansible facts and conf file to remote copy

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'm trying to remote copy to ansible inventory servers a nrpe configuration file
which contain a line with {{ ansible_eno1.ipv4.address }}.
This file is called nrpe.j2 as src and dest nrpe.cfg

After running the playbook, the file has been copied on remote servers, but the nrpe.cfg still contains the line with {{ ansible_eno1.ipv4.address }}. I was expecting to see the ip adress of the eno1 interface.

can you help ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us a snippet from your playbook?

Answer (score 0):

To interpolate values you should use [`template` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html#template-module), not `copy`.